# PHP Posting Form back in header

Tags: php, forms, post, redirect, header

In my web site, I'm doing form checks on server side. When an unexpected input comes from the user i want to post the form back where it comes from. I've found some user defined classes and function on php.net but they didn't work. Can anyone help me about this?

Assume i have a `addCompany.php` page and it has a form. And I have a second page `action.php`.
The form in `addCompany.php` is sent to `action.php` page. I check the form for validation I see an error aand i want to post the form back to the `addCompany.php`. Normally I can send it by querystring however it is not safe because of the character limit. Therefore, i want to sent the form back while i'm redirecting like this `header('Location:addCompany.php')`

Answer (score 0):

The usual procedure is to process the form on the same page and if the validation is ok you redirect to the next stage, otherwise continue back to the form.

Here's a pseudocodish example:

```
<?php
// form.php

if( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) && form_validates( $_POST ) ) {
    // do what you want with the data
    // redirect to the next stage
    header( 'Location: next.php' );
    die();
}

// didn't validate or no submit yet, show the form again

if( isset( $_POST[ 'email' ] ) ) {
    $email = $_POST[ 'email' ];
}
else {
    $email = '';
}
?>
<form action="form.php"> <!-- submit to same page -->
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
<?php if( /* email field didn't validate */ ) {
    echo 'Please enter a valid email address';
} ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: can you read the question again i've edited. I think there was a misunderstanding

Comment: Right, my suggestion is that you combine action.php and addCompany.php into single script. That way you don't have to think about redirecting the page after validation error because you already are there; just let the script show the form again.

Comment: My system is not that simple i cannot modify my system as you suggested.